# Apache Non-Vhost Redirect

Tags: apache, redirect

I want to force all server requests not matching one of my configured vhosts to redirect to my company's home page?

Currently my primary DocumentRoot is set to my home site directory, so non-vhost request **do serve** home page content; however, the domain name **does not** change. How can I force this?

Also, my primary ServerName is commented out by default. Is setting this recommended? And if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first virtual host found in the apache config will be the default host if there is no ServerName match. So add a default host first that redirects to your companies home page:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver
    Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

If you have more than one IP address and different listeners `x.x.x.x:80` then it can be a bit more complex as apache actually looks for a match on the combination of listener and servername. But it's not hard to resolve.

If the primary servername is commented out then apache will try to figure this out at start up. It's usually not an issue when using VirtualHost directives with ServerName local to each vhost.

Comment: How would this work with additional VirtualHost(s) (*:80) with assigned ServerName(s)?

Comment: Never mind, I got it working without requiring the ServerName within the VirtualHost.